# Executing Unix Script through plink from JAVA Runtime

Tags: java, plink

I am using below code to trigger script of Unix through Java.I am not able to figure out why this command is not working.

```
    String cmd="E:\\plink.exe -ssh -l user -pw p123 10.xxx.xx.xx \"sh /home/try.sh\"";
    System.out.println(cmd);
    Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) ;
    process.destroy();
```

Do i need to make some correction in it?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? is the command running fine when you try through command prompt?

Comment: @Hirak: Cmd is working properly and i am  not getting any error in Tom Cat Log folder

Comment: I would recommend try this out in a hello world main program first and check if there are any error. Your code looks fine. Only suggestion will be, instead of a String cmd, use a string array. Something like String cmd[] ={"E:\\plink.exe", "-ssh" ....};

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec only starts the specified program/process. You immediately destroy it before it has time to connect and send the commmand, as you want it to. At a minimum you should .waitFor() it to complete.

You don't say if the script produces (any) output. If it does and you want anything to happen with that output, like being displayed or saved someplace, you need to read from Process.getInputStream() and do your thing. Also if your script needs input (less common) you need to write it to .getOutputStream().